# No profiles available

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, profile

I'm using the `maven-helper-plugin` to exermine which profiles are available.

My current `settings.xml` in my own profile folder contains following definitions:

```
        <profile>
            <id>cqDevAuthorProfile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                ...
            </properties>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>localinstance</id>
                    ...
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>localinstance</id>
                    ...
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>cqDevPublishProfile</id>
            <properties>
                            ...
            </properties>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>localinstance</id>
                                 ...
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>localinstance</id>
                                ...
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
```

The `pom.xml` which I use looks as follow:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>all-profiles</goal>
                        <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration></configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>           
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After invokation of **all-profiles** it produced following output:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:all-profiles (default) @ maven-multi-enviroment-deployment-plugin ---
[WARNING] No profiles detected!
```

while the goal **active-profiles** produced the output:

```
[INFO] 
Active Profiles for Project '...:maven-multi-enviroment-deployment-plugin:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT': 

The following profiles are active:

 - cqDevAuthorProfile (source: settings.xml)
```

My question: What runs wrong or where is my mistake at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today a went back to this issue and could find out that only profiles will be printed out, if they declared in the same `pom.xml` where the plugin invokation is.
The [documantation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/all-profiles-mojo.html) for *all-profiles* says

> Displays a list of available profiles under the **current project**.

While the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/active-profiles-mojo.html) of the command *active-profiles* says:

> Displays a list of the profiles which are currently active for **this build**.

The conclusion from that is, the result is correct and I did missunderstand the description..

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, cause the profile is activated by default based on the following snippet:

```
<activation>
  <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```